# on-premise dialogflow SDK

Tags: sdk, dialogflow-es

To the best of our understanding Dialogflow is a Cloud enabled solution provider. Is there any possibility to get an on-premise edition of Dialogflow SDK for developing a home grown ChatBOT?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. You have to build your own NLP engine in that case. Try using [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) or [NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/) + [Scikit Learn](http://scikit-learn.org/) to experiment building your own NLP engine.

Comment: Another alternative is to use [AutoML for natural language](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/quickstart)